# UPDATE / DROP in Composite Types Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named DATA_FT of

```
id   | integer
time |  timestamp without time zone
data | data[]
```

and type data[] Composite

```
CREATE TYPE data AS ( 
    A double precision, 
    B double precision, 
    C double precision,  
    E double precision, 
);
```

My question is how to **rename** column E with D?

And how to write a query to **drop** all data where e.g. A=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rename your attribute using [`ALTER TYPE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-altertype.html):

```
ALTER TYPE data
RENAME ATTRIBUTE E TO D;
```

---

To access your type attributes in queries, you use `<column>.<attribute>`, so to delete rows where `A = 1` (assuming `col` is of type `data`):

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE col.A = 1;
```

Comment: :D , i found it , but when i'm tested with select in my data give me 
`ERROR: attribute notation .A applied to type data [], which is not a composite type`
`LINE 1: select (data).A from  data `

Comment: Ah, I missed that your column type is a `data[]` (not just `data`). So is your goal to remove items in that array where `A = 1`, or to remove rows where any item in that array contains `A = 1`?

Comment: yeah that's what i want exactly

Comment: i fixed with other method you are only one that he answer me so take best answer